# AWS API-Gateway Caching settings not visible in Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

following the AWS docs for enabling `Caching` for APIs in API-Gateway - **I can not find any settings for Caching in there.**

It seems that I have an old version of the Console, maybe?

Here is what I see:
[image]

Comment: Indeed, your interface seems different than mine... Nothing relevant when you edit the stage ?

Comment: yes, its just this...very weired...can you share maybe a link to the settings page for caching? maybe I get there.

Comment: For me that's Stage > Parameter tab (which don't appear on your console) (https://<region>.console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/home?region=<region>#/apis/<apiId>/stages/<apiStage>) What is your region ? Maybe it might affect

Comment: ohio - us-east-2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using **HTTP API**, not **REST API**. Caching is **not aviabaile** for HTTP API ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html)):

[image]

Subsequently, if you want to develop API with caches, you need to use REST API.

Comment: @skm No problem. Glad it helped :-)